# \begin{titlepage} inside a newcommand

Tags: macros, titles

I want to create a generic document with a given template of style (called `template.cls`), and for the title page I want people just to write down the title, everything else should be in the template.

What I thought to do is  :

```
\newcommand{pagegarde}[1]{%
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[above=4.79cm] (entete) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics{entete.jpg}};
\node[below=2cm,text width=15cm] (departement) at (entete.260) {\huge \bfseries \color{red}{Direction...  \\[0.4cm] Département...}};
\node[below=3cm,text width=15cm] (titre) at (departement.south) {\Huge \bfseries \begin{spacing}{1.15} \color{red}{#1} \end{spacing}};
\node[above=1.5cm,right=2cm] at (current page.south west) {\Large \color{red}{\today}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
}
```

and I included this command into my template.

But when I run the code, Latex does not like this kind of `\newcommand`. I guess it is because there is a `\begin{titlepage}` in it. Originally I had this code in my main document (without the `\newcommand` then), and it worked right.

Any suggestion to do what I want ?

Comment: `\newcommand{\pagegarde}`, not `\newcommand{pagegarde}` ;-) In case this should not be the only error, please post a document, not such fragments only!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks !! I proofread my code, tried several things but I didn't pay attention to that... I feel confuse !

Comment: I hope it will work then ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it works perfectly !!

Comment: Ah, that's fine!

Comment: If this is a class, wouldn't it be better to use the standard `\maketitle`?

Comment: Please please please, give the class a proper name and don't call it `template.cls`. PLEASE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error was caused by a typo (missing `\\` in macro name)

Comment: @Johannes_B It was just a temporary name before finalizing the projet !

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I completely agree with you on closing this topic